# How to filter for rows containing NA?

Tags: r, dataframe

If in x or y is NA, I want to keep this row containing NA and discard the rows, where both, x and y are not NA. I tried with `dplyr::filter()`, `purrr::keep()` and more but nothing worked.
It is essential to do that conditionally and not by the row number since my data set is too large for that.

```r
library(tibble, quietly = T, warn.conflicts = F)
library(dplyr, quietly = T, warn.conflicts = F)

df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~x, ~y, 
  "id_1", 1, NA,
  "id_2", 3, NA,
  "id_3", NA, 29,
  "id_4", -99, 0,
  "id_5", -98, 28,
) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name))

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   name      x     y
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 id_1      1    NA
#> 2 id_2      3    NA
#> 3 id_3     NA    29
#> 4 id_4    -99    0
#> 5 id_5    -98    28
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The target is to keep rows like 1 to 3.

Comment: What happens when both x and y are NA, would you keep that row?

Comment: Yes, I would also want to keep that row.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `filter()` with `if_any` to filter for rows with NA values. For example

```
df %>% filter(if_any(everything(), is.na))
```

If you just wanted to use a range of columns rather than all, you could use

```
df %>% filter(if_any(c(x, y), is.na))
df %>% filter(if_any(x:y, is.na))
df %>% filter(if_any(-name, is.na))
```

for example

Comment: Works! For me, also this slightly different code is working: ```df %>% filter(if_any(.cols = c(x, y), funs::is_na))```

Comment: That looks like a typo, can't find a package called `funs`. I suspect you meant to say `.fun = is.na`?

Comment: Note that the recommendation would be not to be use set parameter names that begin with `.` by name unless you really need to. Usually it reads better without it.

Comment: Isn't this a stand-alone package? https://github.com/tidyverse/funs
```is_na``` from rlang and naniar did not work, however.

Answer (score 2):

Using *rowSums*, check if at least one NA in a row:

```
df[ rowSums(is.na(df)) == 1, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Base R solutions

```
df[!complete.cases(df),] 

df[is.na(df$x) | is.na(df$y),] # if you want to specify specific columns
```

### Alternative packages solution

```
library(hacksaw)
df %>% keep_na(x, y, .logic = 'OR')
```

### Output

```
> # A tibble: 3 × 3
>   name      x     y
>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 id_1      1    NA
> 2 id_2      3    NA
> 3 id_3     NA    29
```